# Flat Earth approximation: forward and reverse formulas

Tags: coordinate-system, navigation

For *very* small distances (< 100 m) I need to go back and forth between "polar coordinates" (i.e. bearing and distance) and "equirectangular projection".

I'm not sure whether I understand them correctly. Here what I've done:

```
double refLat, refLon; // reference (initial) coordinates in radians
double bearing, distance; // target definition

double x = distance * cos(bearing);
double y = distance * sin(bearing);

double targetLon = refLon + x;
double targetLat = refLat + y;
```

now I need to calculate the bearing and the distance from my current position to the target:

```
double currLat, currLon; // current position
double targetLat, targetLon; // target position

double meanLat = (currLat + targetLat) / 2;
double dLon = (targetLon - currLon) * cos(meanLat);
double dLat = (targetLat - currLat);

double distance = sqrt(pow(dLon, 2), pow(dLat, 2)) * 6371.0;
double bearing = atan2(dLat, dLon);
```

I'm not sure how to take in account the cos(meanLat) and Earth's radius in the first function.

Comment: What is the bearing relative to? Can you set a local (0,0)?

Comment: Relative to the reference coordinate (refLat, refLon)

Comment: stupid questions on my part; sorry!